# Chatting with Python Telegram Bot from Command Line for testing Handlers

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot

I have a Python Telegram bot consisting of a set of handlers (as from `telegram.ext`). In my `main.py` for starting the bot, I create a `telegram.ext.Updater` using my API-token, then I add the handlers to its `telegram.ext.Dispatcher`.

However, I would like to be able to test my developing branch bot without having to run an "official" tokenized bot instance (which leads to down times of the actual bot whenever I am developing).

Of course I could create a whole new bot from BotFather as a testing version and use that token instead. But is there a leaner approach, for example so I can chat with my bot from command line?

Since the core of the problem is the decision of which handler to use for an incoming update, my first idea was to simulate whatever  `telegram.ext.Dispatcher.process_update` is doing myself. But I do not know the inner workings of the `python-telegram-bot` library good enough to achieve this.

Any opinions/experiences/workarounds for this? Greetings from Germany!